# Empty array out of a for loop

Tags: python, matlab

I am converting a MATLAB code to Python code, I am sorry that I can not provide the full code, this is only one function. But I get an empty array here in this part as "aux_mx". Could you please help me with this?

```
def dyn_pr_split_w_aux(data, ygreki, par, par_sig_min):

    N = len(data)
    # aux_mx
    aux_mx = np.zeros((N, N))
    for kk in range(N - 1):
        for jj in range(kk + 1, N): #
            aux_mx[kk, jj] = my_qu_ix_w(data[kk:(jj - 1)], ygreki[kk:(jj - 1)], par, par_sig_min)

    return aux_mx


def my_qu_ix_w(invec, yinwec, par, par_sig_min):

    invec = invec.reshape((-1, 1))
    yinwec = yinwec.reshape((-1, 1))
    if ((invec[len(invec)] - invec[0] <= par_sig_min) or (np.sum(yinwec) <= 1.0e-3)): 
        wyn = np.inf
    else:
        wwec = yinwec / (np.sum(yinwec))
        wyn1 = (par + np.sqrt(np.sum(np.dot(((invec - np.sum(np.dot(invec, wwec))) ** 2), wwec)))) / (
                    np.max(invec) - np.min(invec))
        wyn = wyn1
    return wyn1
```

This is the MATLAB implementation:

```
function aux_mx=dyn_pr_split_w_aux(data,ygreki,PAR,PAR_sig_min)

     N=length(data);

     % aux_mx
     aux_mx=zeros(N,N);
     for kk=1:N-1
       for jj=kk+1:N
          aux_mx(kk,jj)= my_qu_ix_w(data(kk:jj-1),ygreki(kk:jj-1),PAR,PAR_sig_min);
       end
   end

function wyn=my_qu_ix_w(invec,yinwec,PAR,PAR_sig_min)
invec=invec(:);
yinwec=yinwec(:);
if (invec(length(invec))-invec(1))<=PAR_sig_min || sum(yinwec)<=1.0e-3
  wyn=inf;
else
   wwec=yinwec/(sum(yinwec));
   wyn1=(PAR+sqrt(sum(((invec-sum(invec.*wwec)).^2).*wwec)))/(max(invec)-min(invec));
   wyn=wyn1;
end
```

I believe I am making a mistake in indexing.

Comment: ```range(N-1)``` will give ```0,1,2,...,(N-1)```. Your loop in the MATLAB code goes from 1 to (n-1), if I am reading it correctly

Comment: @moosearch `range(N-1)` will produce `N-1` values, starting at 0 and with `N-2` as the last value. This matches the MATLAB loop.

Comment: @Shi What do you mean with "an empty array"? Do you mean all values are 0? Is `GaussianMixModel.my_qu_ix_w` being called? Does it return 0 every time? This is the most likely thing you should look into.

Comment: Please read [mre]. If we don't have complete code, we don't know what is happening, so will have a much harder time guessing at the problem. You should definitely not provide "the full code", you should provide minimal code that reproduces your problem. Showing one function that calls an unknown function, and without telling us what the inputs are, is next to useless.

Comment: Is this the function you're calling? https://github.com/ZAEDPolSl/Spec-GMM/blob/master/ms_gmm/my_qu_ix_w.m

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes, this is exactly the code that I am converting. Actually the error is being thrown form this function, because what "aux_mx" returns is an empty array with size of zero

Comment: If `np.zeros((N,N))` is an array with size zero, that means `N` is zero.

Comment: Also note that `invec[len(invec)]` must be wrong in Python, as you're always reading one past the last element. But maybe `len(invec)` is 1 rather than the number of elements in the array. Note that MATLAB `length(x)` is the same as `max(size(x))`, whereas in Python `len(x)` is the size of the first dimension, and you reshaped the array to a Nx1 array, or a 1xN array, I'm not sure.

Comment: @CrisLuengo the size of aux_mx = np.zeros((N, N)) is 3*3

Comment: Then what does "because what 'aux_mx' returns is an empty array with size of zero" mean?

Comment: @CrisLuengo data and ygreki are not empty arrays before going through that for loop inside dyn_pr_split_w_aux, so aux_mx is initialized as np.zeros((N, N)) which is a 3*3 matrix but by going through that for loop aux_mx returns [], and I receive this error "IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0" for the line:  if ((invec[len(invec)] - invec[0] <= par_sig_min) or (np.sum(yinwec) <= 1.0e-3)):

Comment: Oh, I see. If `jj=kk+1`, then `data[kk:(jj - 1)]` is `data[kk:kk]`, which is an empty slice. MATLAB indexes `[start:end]`, `end` included, in Python `end` is not included.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you so much I changed (jj - 1) to jj and it solved the issue. many thanks for your help.